# How can I save a csv file with the name of a tkinter entry?

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I am currently working on a programm with pandas and tkinter.
I build a tkinter entry where you are supposed to write down the file name of the new csv, but the saving does not work if I use a variable instead of a direct string for the new csv name.
Are there any possibillities to work with inputs from tkinter entries?

part of my code:

```
`main=tkinter.Tk()
 a=tkinter.Entry(main,width=50,bg='red')
 c=a.get()
 c=str(c)
 def l():  
    df.to_csv(c)
 a2=tkinter.Button(main,text='change name',width=50,bg='yellow',command=l)
 a2.pack()
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait to call `get` until you actually need the value. In your code, you're calling `a.get()` about a millisecond after the `Entry` widget was created, well before the user has a chance to enter any data.

Move the call to `a.get()` inside of `l`:

```
def l():  
    c = a.get()
    df.to_csv(c)
```

Comment: It sadly does not work. It does not recognize the a entry

Comment: @Dan: It absolutely will work in the context of the code in the question. If your real code doesn't recognize the entry, that's a separate problem. The solution to the question you asked is to wait to call `get` until you need the value. It's up to you to make sure you can access the entry widget.